# MyPy using other Pyhton version as in venv? (Positional-only parameters are only supported in Python 3.8 and greater)

Tags: python, version, mypy, python-poetry, gitpod

MyPy thinks it has to check for Python <3.8 when instead it should use 3.10

As you can see, Python3.10 is active

```
(myvenv) gitpod /workspace/myfolder (mybranch) $ python --version
Python 3.10.7
```

however mypy think its <3.8?

```
(myvenv) gitpod /workspace/myfolder (mybranch) $ mypy -p my_folder_with_code
```

```
/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/poetry/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyi:641:
error: Positional-only parameters are only supported in Python 3.8 and greater
Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)
```

even `mypy --python-version 3.10 -p my_folder_with_code` produces the same error

This happens only in this platform (gitpod). On other devices it runs fine (so no error in code)

I googled around but did found what i'm looking for... can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i found it out miself. Apparently it was a [bug in mypy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22412).

Update MyPy and it works again
`pip install -U mypy`
Or in my case
`poetry update mypy`